# What should be the table structure for this situation

Tags: sql, database

I am working on a social platform like web site. I'm not sure what should be the table structure of this situation;

I will have trips that users will create. And users can add users to the trips that they traveled with.

So;

> ```
> >One Trip
>   >Many users
> ```

Should I create the with just two columns;

> ```
> >tripID
> >userID
> ```

and adding new row for every new user for the same trip ?

Or do you have any other opinion ?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several different relationships here:

- A trip has a creator
- A trip has many users that go on the trip
- A user goes on many trips

This means a one-to-many for trips to user for creating trips (a user can create many trips, a trip has one creator).

You also have a many-to-many, as a user can go on many trips, and trips can have many users, so you need a join table for that.

I would name the join table trip_users, as that is the two joined entities in alphabetical order, which is a standard in some places:

### trips

- id
- creator_id (refers to the user that created the trip)

### users

- id

### trip_users

- user_id
- trip_id

Comment: ok, I have 2 tables users and trips. So I'll have userTrips table, so if I have 1 trip and 50 users for this trip I'll add 50 rows with the same tripID right ? so I'll repeat the same id in tripID column 50 times. Is this the best option for this ?

Comment: @MustafaTok - That is correct, you would have 50 rows with the same tripID. The table would require a composite Primary Key of 'userID' and 'tripID' to ensure a user could not be on the same trip twice.

Comment: @Tony is right, and thanks for talking about PKs.  For that matter, you may also want to add a foreign key (FK) from trips.creator_id to users.id, a FK from trip_users.user_id to users.id, and a FK between trip_users.trip_id to trips.id

Comment: Some people also like to have a surrogate key on the trip_users table, and then a unique constraint on the user_id & trip_id, but a think the composite PK from them is a better solution.

Comment: You could move the information about the creator of a trip to the 'trip_users' table, that way you would not have to record the 'user_id' twice or perform multiple joins to the Users table to get all the information about a trip. It's probably not the correct *formal* normalisation but it might speed things up if you have a lot of trips and users.

Comment: @Tony that is also a good option, but in that case I would add a boolean to the trip_users table to indicate which user was the creator, as they may have different privileges regarding the trip, and you don't want to lose that information.

Answer (score 1):

You have three distinct objects here.
A user can be on many trips
A trip can have many users.  By definition this is a many-to-many relationship. For most RDBMS it needs to be resolved though an associative table. (which is the 3rd object)

### TABLE: user

- userID
- userInfo...

### TABLE: Trip

- TripID
- TripInfo...

### TABLE: userTrips

- userID
- TripID
- userTripInfo...

Comment: ok, I have 2 tables users and trips. So I'll have userTrips table, so if I have 1 trip and 50 users for this trip I'll add 50 rows with the same tripID right ? so I'll repeat the same id in tripID column 50 times. Is this the best option for this ?

Comment: yes.  It's the generally accepted practice for database normalization.  This is because the UserID, TripID are UNIQUE to that table. you shouldn't ever have duplicates. repeating 1 Id 50 times is better than repeating all the user information 50 times.  Think of the id as nothing more than a pointer back to where all the good information is.